# Are the Olympics a Federation-wide event?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, olympics

I noticed the following line in *DS9* ["Take Me Out to the Holosuite"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/554.htm):

> **EZRI DAX:** My third host Emony was an Olympic gymnast.

Is Ezri referring to an analogue of the Olympic Games that take place on the Trill homeworld (and perhaps the universal translator considers these games to be "Olympic")?

Or have Earth's Olympic Games become a Federation-wide event by the 24th Century?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication (based on lines that were scripted, but then cut from [TNG: Code of Honor](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/104.txt)) is that the Olympics are a Federation-wide event, albeit one that has special significance to humanity.

> **TASHA:** [to Data] *Those were my early interests... strength, daring, dominant males... and that's why Lutan attracts me. To me,
>   he's like a **Federation Olympic Games** hero. But do I want to become his
>   so-called "First One", marry him? That would be nonsense!*

---

Based on the vast disparity in strength and agility between the various races of the Federation, I can only presume that there are different categories for those with less-than-human, human and superhuman skills.